# Android NDK Native method not found error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to build android application using native code so i want to test if ndk runs successfully.When i try to run my first hello world project
log cat says,

```
01-21 23:30:06.780: E/AndroidRuntime(939): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 23:30:06.780: E/AndroidRuntime(939): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Native method not found: com.example.ndktesting.MainActivity.invokeNativeFunction:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

I checked some stackoverflow answers but could not find my answer.Here is my code for java and c.I am using android ndk r8d version.

```
//ndktest.c

#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

extern "C"{
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL   Java_com_example_ndktesting_ndktest_MainActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject  thiz)
};

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL   Java_com_example_ndktesting_ndktest_MainActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject  thiz){
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
}
```

Here is my MainActivity java code:

```
package com.example.ndktesting;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
    //declare the native code function - must match ndktest.c
    private native String invokeNativeFunction();

    public native String  unimplementedinvokeNativeFunction();

    // load the library - name matches jni/Android.mk 
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ndktest");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // this is where we call the native code
        String hello = invokeNativeFunction();

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(hello).show();
    }
}
```

Android make file code:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndktest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndktest.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Please note that this question involves one specific cause (mismatching package name) for a much more common error message which can have countless causes.  Readers who have not mismatched the names are not going to find the solution here - they have a fundamentally different and unknown problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your package/class names do not match.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL   Java_com_example_ndktesting_ndktest_MainActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject  thiz)
```

Would be a method in the class

```
com.example.ndktesting.ndktest.MainActivity
```

However your actual code

```
package com.example.ndktesting;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

causes it to look for

```
com.example.ndktesting.MainActivity.invokeNativeFunction
```

without the "ndktest"

Once you make the names match it should either work, or expose the next issue.

Comment: yes i tried without "ndktest" but i throws me same error.please help me.

Comment: voila i fixed.Thanks Chris.

Comment: What was the problem? EDIT: i found that problem with my code was missing extern "C" {}

Comment: @Kuru Kshetran : Can you please clarify your answer? Where you add  extern "C" {}? I have same error as you.

Comment: Note that as the question says C and not C++, extern "C" is not the solution to the stated problem, though it could be a solution for someone else who is using C++ and thus has a different problem.

Comment: saved my day. yes renamed package is the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the difference in the package and works.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am facing the issue even though my package/class names matching. can you have a look here? Thanks in advance! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269981/jmethodid-was-null-for-a-method-with-kotlin