# Why FFMPEG commands not working in marshmallows and lollipop?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

why my code is not working in marshmallows and lollipop devices. or any idea how to use FFMPEG in that versions. any help.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kru.ffmpeglibs.FFmpeg;
import com.kru.ffmpeglibs.FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler;
import com.kru.ffmpeglibs.FFmpegLoadBinaryResponseHandler;
import com.kru.ffmpeglibs.exceptions.FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException;
import com.kru.ffmpeglibs.exceptions.FFmpegNotSupportedException;

public class CommandsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FFmpeg fFmpeg;
private Button btnGenerate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fFmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(CommandsActivity.this);
    executeBinary();

    btnGenerate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGenerate);
    btnGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String[] ffmpegCommand = { "-i "
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                .getPath()
                        + "/vid.mp4"
                        + " -r 10 "
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                .getPath()
                        + "/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/frame_%05d.jpg" };

                executeCommand(ffmpegCommand);

            } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void executeCommand(String[] cmd)
        throws FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException {

    fFmpeg.execute(cmd, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {

            Toast.makeText(CommandsActivity.this, "Sucesses..",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            System.out.println(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(String message) {
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "On Process",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(CommandsActivity.this, "Fail this",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(CommandsActivity.this, "Finish",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

private void executeBinary() {

    try {
        fFmpeg.loadBinary(new FFmpegLoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {

            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }); } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {   e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code but it still not working. please tell me what is wrong in the code
The exception i got is something like this.

```
02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.kru.ffmpeglibs.ArmArchHelper.cpuArchFromJNI:()Ljava/lang/String;
02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at com.kru.ffmpeglibs.ArmArchHelper.cpuArchFromJNI(Native Method)
02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at com.kru.ffmpeglibs.CpuArchHelper.getCpuArch(CpuArchHelper.java:61)
02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at com.kru.ffmpeglibs.FFmpeg.loadBinary(FFmpeg.java:40)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at com.kru.sampleffmpeg.MainActivity.loadFFMpegBinary(MainActivity.java:68)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at com.kru.sampleffmpeg.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
 02-22 11:18:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: working on other version?

Comment: yes its working on other version perfectly

Comment: I need to add so other command as like reverse video and slow motion video

Comment: you have get any solution for that? @Andy Developer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14444952/5068931

Comment: I do the same but still its not working it gives the same error as previous one.

Answer (score 2):

Lets see FFmpeg setup in onther way just you have to put `compile 'com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg:FFmpegAndroid:0.2.5'` in your gradle. Now Follow step using [this](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) link, now you have must to call `ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {`, before use of execute command. Other wise get problem.  Now see below code and Sceenshot

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
Button click;
FFmpeg fFmpeg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fFmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
    executeBinary();

    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChk);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Log.e("Log",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString());

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                String cmd=editText.getText().toString();

               // frameCount.mp4

                executeCommand(cmd);
            } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });


}

private void executeCommand(String cmd) throws FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException {

    fFmpeg.execute(cmd, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sucesses..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            System.out.println(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(String message) {
          //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "On Process", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail this", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

private void executeBinary() {

    try {
        fFmpeg.loadBinary(new FFmpegLoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

See Below Image use your command in EditText as input `-i /storage/emulated/0/frameCount.mp4 -r 7 /storage/emulated/0/frame%03d.jpg`

[image: Images]

Comment: I was implement the link you given but I got the exception.
: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.kru.ffmpeglibs.ArmArchHelper.cpuArchFromJNI:()Ljava/lang/String;
: at com.kru.ffmpeglibs.ArmArchHelper.cpuArchFromJNI(Native Method)
:at com.kru.ffmpeglibs.CpuArchHelper.getCpuArch(CpuArchHelper.java:15)
: at com.kru.ffmpeglibs.FFmpeg.loadBinary(FFmpeg.java:40)
: at com.kru.sampleffmpeg.MainActivity.loadFFMpegBinary(MainActivity.java:67)

Comment: have you impliment above code ? make new project and test my code. that work for me.

Comment: see my updated answer i do the same but it still give me the error in 6.0 also in 4.2 devices. not check any other devices yet

Comment: chat.stackoverflow.com come at we discuss about that

Comment: @Android I tried - `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4` command using your mentioned code, but that seemed failed. Can you plz tell, whats wrong in that command, as the same command is already working, when tried using Ubuntu terminal

Comment: Please check my query here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/39365128/1479511