# jmethodID was NULL for a method with Kotlin

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, kotlin, native

I am using a native library and having the exception below even though the method exists. I have a nativeInit function that is also exported to MapController and it works as expected. However, the nativeLoadScene method causes an error.

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jmethodID was NULL
    in call to CallObjectMethodV
    from int com.demo.lib.MyController.nativeLoadScene(long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])
```

JNI methods

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_demo_lib_MyController_nativeInit(JNIEnv *jniEnv, jobject obj, jobject tangramInstance, jobject assetManager) {
   ...
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_demo_lib_MyController_nativeLoadScene(JNIEnv* jniEnv, jobject obj, jlong mapPtr, jstring path, jobjectArray updateStrings) {
   ...
}
```

com.demo.lib.MyController.kt

```
companion object {
    init {
        System.loadLibrary("c++_shared")
    }
}

// this works
external fun nativeInit(instance: MapController, assetManager: AssetManager?): Long

// this gives error
external fun nativeLoadScene(mapPtr: Long, path: String, updateStrings: Array<String?>?): Int
```

Comment: The init() function that you show here is in Kotlin, not C++. Maybe your problem is that you don't load your native library, only the STL (libc++_shared.so).

Comment: @AlexCohn I've edited the question, sorry for the inconvenience. by init, i meant nativeInit method inside c++ class

Comment: I believe that you should pass `Array<String?>?` as **jobject**, not **jobjectArray**.

Comment: @AlexCohn: An `Array<T>` in Kotlin is at the bytecode level equivalent to a `T[]` in Java. So `Array<String?>?` means `@Nullable String[]`.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate a problem when trying to call a Java method from native code, so where is the code for `Java_com_demo_lib_MyController_nativeLoadScene`?